# How do I segregate C++ code without impacting performance?

Tags: c++, image-processing, refactoring, compiler-optimization

I'm having trouble refactoring my C++ code. The code itself is barely 200 lines, if even, however, being an image processing affair, it loops a lot, and the roadblocks I'm encoutering (I assume) deal with very gritty details (e.g. memory access).

The program produces a correct output, but is supposed to ultimately run in realtime. Initially, it took ~3 minutes per 320x240px frame, but it's at around 2 seconds now (running **approximately as fast on mid-range workstation and low-end laptop hardware**; red flag?). Still a far cry from 24 times per second, however. Basically, any change I make propagates through the millions of repetitions, and tracking my beginner mistakes has become exponentially more cumbersome as I approach the realtime mark.

At 2 points, the program calculates a less computationally expensive variant of Euclidean distance, called *taxicab* distance (the sum of absolute differences).

Now, the abridged version:

```cpp
std::vector<int> positiveRows, positiveCols;
/* looping through pixels, reading values */
distance = (abs(pValues[0] - qValues[0]) + abs(pValues[1] - qValues[1]) + abs(pValues[2] - qValues[2]));
if(distance < threshold)
{
  positiveRows.push_back(row);
  positiveCols.push_back(col);
}
```

If I wrap the functionality, as follows:

```cpp
int taxicab_dist(int Lp,
                 int ap,
                 int bp,
                 int Lq,
                 int aq,
                 int bq)
{
    return (abs(Lp - Lq) + abs(ap - aq) + abs(bp - bq));
}
```

and call it from within the same .cpp file, there is no performance degradation. If I **instead declare and define it in separate .hpp / .cpp files**, I get a **significant slowdown**. This directly opposes what I've been told in my undergraduate courses ("*including a file is the same as copy-pasting it*"). The closest I've gotten to the original code's performance was by declaring the arguments **const**, but it still takes ~100ms longer, which my judgement says is not affordable for such a meager task. Then again, I don't see why it slows down (significantly) if I also make them **const int&**. Then, when I do the most sensible thing, and choose to take arrays as arguments, again I take a performance hit. I don't even dare attempt any templating shenanigans, or try making the function modify its behavior so that it accepts an arbitrary number of pairs, at least not until I understand what I've gotten myself into.

**So my question is**: how can take the calculation definition to a separate file, and have it perform **the same as** the original solution? Furthermore, should the fact that compilers are optimizing my program to **run 2 seconds instead of 15** be a **huge red flag** (bad algorithm design, not using more exotic C++ keywords / features)?

I'm guessing the main reason why I've failed to find an answer is because I don't know what is the name of this stuff. I've heard the terms "*vectorization*" tossed around quite a bit in the HPC community. Would this be related to that?

If it helps in any way at all, the code it its entirety can be found [here](https://github.com/bcoka/abwStereoMatching/blob/refactor/src/stereo.cpp).

Comment: How about putting the function in a header file, and mark it `inline`?

Comment: Also, you could try to [profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) your program to see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: You could pre-allocate or **reserve** space in your vector for either the average number of elements or the maximum.  Vectors start out "small" then perform reallocations as necessary.  The reallocations take time and fragment memory.

Comment: Try **inline** of small functions, such as your `taxicab_dist`.  The overhead of calling and returning may be greater than or equal to the performance in the function.

Comment: Alternative: enable LTO (Link Time Optimization). And for the record, there is no contradiction: including *is* copy/pasting, but here you copy/paste the *declaration* only (after the split), and the compiler optimizes better when seeing the *definition* of the function rather than just its *declaration*.

Comment: Addeding to @MatthieuM says, when you move functions to other files, the compiler can't make assumptions about the function and can't perform many optimizations like inlining.  If the functions are in one module it can perform more optimizations.  I'm not saying all the code should be in one file.  You can assist the compiler by using these keywords:  `const`, `static` and `inline`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Marking the function as `inline` was a very elegant solution and introduced no overhead as far as I could tell; thank you! :-) I'll just go ahead and mention that I had an "undefined reference" error, caused by the definition of an inline function not being in the header file (gcc).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Unfortunately, as of yet, I don't have a good way to approximate the size of my vectors - the core idea of the algorithm is based on adaptive methods, so `std::vector` is pretty much a luxury at this point. I will take note of this possibility, and try to determine an average size during future development. Thanks for the idea! :-)

Comment: @MatthieuM: Is there a way to cirumvent including only declarations (besides having definitions in the header files)?

Comment: @bcoka: As I mentioned, Link Time Optimization consists in delaying some optimizations after all source files (.cpp, .cxx, ...) of a library/executable have been "digested". It is somewhat slower, but when looking for raw speed a viable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joachim Pileborg says, you should profile first.  Find out where in your program most of the execution time occurs.  This is the place where you should optimize.

**Reserving space in vector**
Vectors start out small and then reallocate as necessary.  This involves allocating a larger space in memory and then copying the old elements to the new vector.  Finally deallocating the memory.  The `std::vector` has the capability of reserving space upon *construction*.  For large sizes of vectors, this can be a time saver, eliminating many reallocations.

**Compiling with speed optimizations**
With modern compilers, you should set the optimizations for high speed and see what they can do.  The compiler writers have many tricks up their sleeve and can often spot locations to optimize that you or I miss.

**Truth is assembly language**
You will need to view the assembly language listing.  If the assembly language shows only two instructions in the area you *think* is the bottleneck, you really can't get faster.

**Loop unrolling**
You may be able to get more performance by copying the content in a `for` loop many times.  This is called *loop unrolling*.  In some processors, branch or jump instructions cost more execution time than data processing instructions.  Unrolling a loop reduces  the number of executed branch instructions.  Again, the compiler may automatically perform this when you raise the optimization level.

**Data cache optimization**
Search the web for "Data cache optimization".  Loading and unloading the data cache wastes time.  If your data can fit into the processor's data cache, it doesn't have to keep loading an unloading (called cache misses).  Also remember to perform all your operations on the data in one place before performing other operations.  This reduces the likelihood of the processor reloading the cache.

**Multi-processor computing**
If your platform has more than one processor, such as a Graphics Processing Unit (GPU), you may be able to delegate some tasks to it.  Be aware that you have also added time by communicating with the other processor.  So for small tasks, the communications overhead may waste the time you gained by delegating.

**Parallel computing**
Similar to multi-processors, you can have the Operating System delegate the tasks.  The OS could delegate to different cores in your processor (if you have a multi-core processor) or it runs it in another thread.  Again there is a cost:  overhead of managing the task or thread and communications.

**Summary**
The three rules of Optimization:

1. Don't
2. Don't
3. Profile
   After you profile, review the area where the most execution takes place.  This will gain you more time than optimizing a section that never gets called.  Design optimizations will generally get you more time than code optimizations.  Likewise, requirement changes (such as elimination) may gain you more time than design optimizations.

After your program is working correctly and is robust, you can optimize, only if warranted.  If your UI is so slow that the User can go get a cup of coffee, it is a good place to optimize.  If you gain 100 milliseconds by optimizing data transfer, but your program waits 1 second for the human response, you have not gained anything.  Consider this as driving really fast to a stop sign.  Regardless of your speed, you still have to stop.

If you still need performance gain, search the web for "Optimizations c++", or "data optimizations" or "performance optimization".

Comment: Regarding raising optimization levels, it's not always guaranteed that it will create faster code. There are many examples where raising from second level (`-O2` on GCC) to third level (`-O3`) actually *lowered* performance. Turning on (or off) individual optimizations might give better results. Experiment!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:  Good point.  I'm only raising the point that optimizations should be tried before a beginner optimizes the code.  I've seen compilers unroll loops for me, I've also seen compilers write different code that has the same performance as code I've written.

Comment: Loop unrolling doesn't seem elegant, and I'd like to avoid it if possible, instead opting to let the compiler handle it to the best of its ability.
Actually, I did some trivial OpenMP and CUDA tests, and this refactoring is essentially prep work for parallelization.
Making an educated guess, I'd say data caches are the primary culprits here (resulting from **very** non-sequential memory access). However, I have yet to learn how to diagnose these sorts of problems. If you guys could recommend any quality resources for getting into profiling, that would be awesome.